# Easylife Switcher throws CloudZoom.quickStart() not defined

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am using ultimo for a client and Easylife Switcher.

Main image changes on clicking from color options [easylife switcher for showing images instead of colors]. However, when mouse is hovered instead of new image, the old image zooms.

After reading through I have done following but problem persists.
product.js was updated to following:

```
    configureForValues: function($super){
    this.fullLoad = true;
    $super();
    this.fullLoad = true;
},
getOptionLabel : function($super, option, price) {
    if (this.getConfigValue(this.config, 'show_added_prices', false)) {
        return $super(option, price);
    }
    return option.label;
}});
```

In JS callback, I have added **CloudZoom.quickStart();**

In console I can see error:

```
ReferenceError: CloudZoom is not defined
```

Comment: Generate issue in github

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and thats what i did to make it work:

- Go to js/easylife_switcher/product.js and add these lines in the function **changeMainImage**:

  `jQuery("#cloudZoom").attr("href", productImage['src']); \\ #cloudZoom being the id of the image for which you have defined zoom
  jQuery("#cloudZoom").attr("gallery", productImage['src']);`

  after:

  `$(image).title = productImage['alt'];`

  So what this does is when we update our main image through EasyLife Switcher, it updates the Cloudzoom link with new image.
- Add this to the textarea **Js Callback after main image change**, at the EasyLife Switcher Configuration:

  `jQuery('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();`

  This re-initializes the cloudzoom so that the pop up which appears when you hover over the main image also grabs the new updated image.

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Thanks @anumtasia. It works. However, on mobile devices it just does not do anything. When I slide, says loading.. and same image remains. Any heads up?

Comment: @techster Your'e Welcome. Did you disable your EasyLife Switcher and checked that Cloud Zoom is working or not without the plugin?

Comment: I disabled it and same problem is there. However, when I visited the link of cloud zoom, it says it should work. Really been putting my head but lost as to where to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using one line for the easylife_switcher js callback worked for me:

```
ProductMediaManager.swapImage('#image-main');
```